# C# GC is not collecting objects with no root

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I read some data from a file (e.g., 1.00E+7 objects) into a list of objects. Then I pass them to another class that will make a conversion on each and then serialize to disk. In this process I have a considerable memory leak.

Using `!dumpheap -stat` I see that few of my classes occupy lots of memory such as following:

```
MT         count     TotalSize ClassName
00185fd0   196180      7847200 Di3BMain.PeakDataClass
0070d25c   392429      9418296 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[DI3.Lambda`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[Di3BMain.PeakDataClass, Di3Main]], Di3]]
00707038   392360     10986080 DI3.B`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[Di3BMain.PeakDataClass, Di3Main]]
00930a0c    15453     12821476 CSharpTest.Net.Collections.BPlusTree`2+Element[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[DI3.B`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[Di3BMain.PeakDataClass, Di3Main]], Di3]][]
7282fe8c   393241     13307220 System.Object[]
72843a70      250    641899364 System.Int32[]
```

Considering the number and the size it's clear that many instances of the same object are created, as I expect (one output-serializ object for one input object). But each of the new objects should be collected as I expect from my code which in very simplified format is as following:

```
serializer.Add(new ConvertedObject( ... ){ ... });
```

To understand the leak I tried to check for the roots of some of the largest entries; for example `MT: 00707038` using `!gcroot -all 00707038`; but what it gives me is `Found 0 roots.`

Given that just before all these stats I force `GC` using following code, I wonder why `GC` is not collecting any of those big objects with no roots ?! even after pushing it !

```
GC.Collect();
GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: Just because the GC *can* collect the objects (if they're not accessible from a root) doesn't mean it has to immediately do so.  it's free to collect the objects whenever it wants.  You also haven't shown us the code.

Comment: @Servy - he calss GC.Collect()

Comment: @HenkHolterman Technically that's just a request to do a collection; one that the GC is free to ignore if it wants.  Regardless, the question lacks a reproducible example; the objects may well be accessible at the time he does the collection.

Comment: But I think those three commands force it to do so immediately.

Comment: If you have a leak (and that's not clear) it's with 600 MB in `System.Int32[]`. But nothing in the posted code about that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, to be honest I have no ideas why `System.Int32[]` cos I don't have any calls for that! Incidentally, code is very long consisting of lots of classes that make different related calls; and I thought it would not be intuitive so I avoided posting them here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `!gcroot -all 00707038` the value `00707038` is address for the Method Table.. To find if an object is rooted or not, you'd want to pick an instance of the class, i.e. use object address, not method table address. Using `dumpheap -mt` (no `-stat`) with the MT address will dump list of objects of given class (in your case the list might be long.. and hence you can think of ways to limit the output, or break after few have been dumped on screen).

Once you have an object address, run `gcroot` on that address.

2. On the flip side, do note that just because object is not rooted, doesn't mean, GC is not collecting it.. depending on the generation the object is in, when the gc last ran for given generation, and when you took the dump, it may be normal for un-rooted objects to show in the dump.

GC may not collect every generation, and every object, unless it thinks system is under memory pressure.

Comment: Exactly. just because you tell GC to collect doesn't mean it will and you shouldn't either call code to tell it to do so for perf and un-deterministic behaviour reasons!

Comment: Thanks, actually I was missing the point you mentioned; however still the problem is not solved yet, `gcroot` for any of the instances keeps giving `Error during command: IDebugClient asked for unimplemented interface` message ... ?! any ideas why ?

Comment: @Hamed I am sorry.. I have never seen that error before.. all I can **guess** is that, from the sound of it, you may have some kind of version mismatch between the debugger and the debugger extension loaded. **1.** Try to ensure that you have latest version of windbg installed (assuming you are using windbg), **2.** and that sos.dll is also loaded from the version of CLR / .Net framework, with which the app was built. If the machine which is running the app has even minor version difference from machine where you are loading the dump, hard to understand errors can come up :( - Hope this helps.

Comment: Another option you may have is, depending on which debugger features you need.. you have the option of using `windbg` or even `VS.Net`.. Many people don't know about the latter being useful for dump debugging or even windbg style memory analysis of a **live** process within VS.Net.. The setup is little too big to list here, you can search more on it on internet anyways.. but in short, while debugging your project, configure it for `Mixed mode debugging` in project properties, and in general, when you break into your process, you can load `sos.dll` and run its commands from `immediate window`.

Comment: @VikasGupta yeah, I checked the points you mentioned, they all match. Still `gcroot` keeps giving the above-mentioned error :(

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `VS.NET`